# Laravel relationship with belongsTo with 0 ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I can't find a way to do this in eloquent. My schema looks something like this.

**Election**

- id
- title

**Position**

- id
- election_id
- title

Right now, the `election_id` can either contain **0** (means applied to all elections) or **any id** from the `elections` table.

My **Election** model contains `hasMany` relationship to the **Positions** model, but right now I am only getting those positions with the same `election_id` but not those rows with 0 values.

*Snippet of my Election model:*

```
public function positions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Position::class, 'election_id', 'id');
}
```

Would this possible with eloquent? Or should I resort to another query? I want to do this in eloquent as much as possible as I need to load the relationship in my **ElectionResource** class.

*Snippet of my ElectionResource class:*

```
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'positions' => PositionResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('positions')),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: so your election/positions table can have records with 0 id??

Comment: The `election_id` in my `positions` table can contain **0**.

Comment: but there won't be any records with id 0 in election table, right??

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: then what you have done so far is alright, election don't have any records with id 0, that's why you are not getting any positions data with 0 election_id

Answer (score 0):

You can make the foreign key column `nullable`:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('election_id')->nullable();
```

And then do something like this:

```
Election::doesntHave('position')->get();
```

If you want to get positions that do not belong to any elections, do this:

```
Position::whereNull('election_id')->get();
```

Comment: Yea, but how will I construct my hasMany relationship?

Comment: @PaulSantos use the same relationship, but use `doesntHave` to get elections without any positions. I've also added a solution to get all positions that do not belong to any election.

Comment: I have to load the `positions` in my Election model. Something like, `Election::with('positions')->get();`

Comment: @PaulSantos this query will only load positions that belong to an election. You'll need to execute the second query to get positions without an election attached as I've shown in the answer.